# CefSharp flash player fullscreen

Tags: c#, .net, flash, fullscreen, cefsharp

I use CefSharp with pepper flash player to show video in my wpf app.
Flash player in full screen mode take all webbrowser control area. But i would like to open flash for real full screen.
Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Implement `IDisplayHandler.OnFullscreenModeChange`, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/47/CefSharp/IDisplayHandler.cs#L44 You'll need to hide the other controls on your `Form` in a fashion that suites your app.

Comment: @amaitland yeah, i know about IDisplayHandler. But i cann't hide other controls. And i would like to take real full screen, not in-app-fullscreen. Is it possible? Maybe i should create a new window? But how to move browser data?

Comment: You'll need to hide the controls, I'm pretty sure you'll find that's what Chromium does. What's real full screen? You just make the window full screen and remove the borders. Anyway, full screen is upto you, just change the state when `OnFullScreenModeChange` is called.

Comment: Remember, `ChromiumWebBrowser` is just a control on your form, the form controls overall width, height, menu bars.....

Comment: Re-parenting the `ChromiumWebBrowser` control appears to be an option, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/commit/7f1f1c5f214e10c77f3c47740e8ef9ac26830be9#diff-c2d72c89ae2f1668e2302d726a1b58aeR32